# Difference of 35 seconds in MySQL time and PHP time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timezone

MySQL:

```
exec("SET time_zone='+05:30';");
now();
```

PHP:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
echo $current_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s ', time());
```

MySQL sets the correct time as IST, but PHP displays time 35 seconds behind IST. Why so?

Comment: Is your MySQL server separate from the PHP server?

Comment: @GregSchmidt No, btw leave the MySQL one as it works fine. The issue is in PHP, it is behind 40 seconds. I added MySQL so that we can see that there is no issue on the server.

Comment: What happens if you don't set the timezone?

Comment: It shows NY time as default is set to `America/New York`

Comment: Correct NY time, or NY time off by 35 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are executing that 2 codes at the same time? There are 2 possibilities:
1. The execution time is different.
2. The php.ini files defines the date_default_timezone_set() is wrong.

Comment: There are myriad possibilities

Comment: That is as far as I know. I'm not sure either if there is another possibilities. What kind of other possibilities you may know? @Strawberry